# Push into object with specific key

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to push some values into one object with a specific key index, something like this:

```
var array = [];
array.push({
  name: "toto",
  function: "Dev"     
})
```

My final object I want to look like this:

```
array = {'user'=>[name:"toto",function:"Dev"]};
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your final 'array' should be object?

Comment: This is not an array

Comment: you need an array or object literal?

Comment: That's an object of arrays: `var x = { [] }` curly brackets are object literals

Comment: what i want is array['user'] = [name:"toto",function:"dev"];

Comment: Why would you call a non-array object "array"??

Comment: @PopAlexandru that format is not valid JS code as it does not support associative arrays. You will need to use an array of objects, exactly as you already are

Comment: var obj = {
user: []}
obj.user.push({
  name: "toto",
  function: "Dev"     
})

Comment: @zabusa No. Objects do not have a `push()` method

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan am not pushing in to an object but to an user array.

Comment: You are now you edited it ;)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan nope.made some changes.but this is what i meant ;)

Answer (score -3):

```
var myArry = [];
myArry['user'] = [];
myArry['user'].push({
  name: "toto",
  function: "Dev"     
});
```

I think you are looking for that

Comment: why are you saying not usefull without understanding ?

Comment: You are creating an *"array like object"*. Probably for no good reason

Comment: How can you tell? Question is ambiguous

Comment: Thank you @Bora Ervasoglu , is exactly what i was looking for

Comment: He said thanks to me ?!? yea that was useful right ? but you gave -3 thanks everybody !